# Batch Script to Search for Softwares by Vendor to a CSV file

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch script to search for software's on a computer by a specific vendor and save the results to a CSV file.... I am tried it with the following script, but it always returns NULL values, not able to figure out the issue.

```
@echo off
Set "serial="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC BIOS Get SerialNumber') Do If Not Defined serial Call :Sub %%A
Set serial 2>Nul
:Sub
Set "serial=%*"
Set "LogFile=%serial%.CSV"

If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
wmic /Append:"%LogFile%" product where "Name like '%Microsoft%'" get Name, Version /Format:CSV

Start "" "%LogFile%"
exit
```

Comment: When Win32_Product is enumerated, it actually performs a full status check on each product. This not only seriously affects your script time, but can also mean that potentially unwanted repairs or modifications are made to those 'products' too. **The official recommendation,** _(not just mine)_, **is not to use Win32_Product**, _(for which `product` is a [tag:wmic] alias)_.

Comment: @ Compo, then how best can this be done?

Comment: Your 'products', should all be in the Windows registry. So it should be quicker and safer to parse the registry keys. Please note however, that whilst it will run more quickly, and safely via the registry, the code will be considerably longer and look more complicated, as a result.

Comment: I'll also ask, as it may still be important, regardless of the method you choose to use, why are you searching for the string `Microsoft` anywhere in the name of the product? There is already a `Vendor` property, which I'd assume is more likely to reflect what you're looking for! _(I doubt that other vendors would have `Microsoft` in their `vendor` property, but possible that some may have it in their `name` property)_

Comment: @ Compo, Microsoft is just an example, I want to actually write a Script to check if a Discovery Agent is installed on a computer or not... I thought I could do this by looking for the vendor of the discovery agent

Comment: If you're just using examples, which are not reflective of the actual task, you should make that clear in your question. AWS, SolarWinds, FreshService, and many other vendors have products name Discovery Agent, can you be more specific? Also, I'm not sure if you're aware, but Win32_Product only works for software installed with Microsoft Installer, so are you definitely only looking for a product which was installed as a MSI?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.... I am actually looking to check if FreshService Discovery Agent is installed on a computer or not

Comment: Thanks for that, at least, as far as I'm aware, that does have an MSI installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NB :*** `%` is needed to be [used as wildcard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263(v=vs.85).aspx)

In this case you should add another percent character `%` to `%Microsfot%` to escape the wilcard of `WMIC` in your batch and become like `%%Microsoft%%`

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Batch Script to Search for Softwares by Vendor to a CSV file
Set "serial="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC BIOS Get SerialNumber') Do If Not Defined serial Call :Sub %%A
Set serial 2>Nul

:Sub
echo(
echo(    Please wait a while ... Searching for installed softwares ....
Set "serial=%*"
Set "LogFile=%serial%.CSV"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
wmic /Append:"%LogFile%" product where "Name like '%%Microsoft%%'" get Name, Version /Format:CSV
Start "" "%LogFile%"
Exit
```

Comment: …but it does still use the recommended against Win32_Product mechanism.